# Finding "Hamiltonian paths" in fixed-size integer partitions

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions, hamiltonian-path

For $ p_k(n) $, the partitions of $ n $ with exactly $ k $ parts, it's possible to order them such that each adjacent pair of partitions differ only by one, i.e. one can be transposed to the other by subtracting 1 from one of its parts and adding 1 to another.

$$
p_4(8)\\
\{5, 1, 1, 1\}\\
\{4, 2, 1, 1\}\\
\{3, 3, 1, 1\}\\
\{3, 2, 2, 1\}\\
\{2, 2, 2, 2\}\\
$$

This (and its reverse) is the only ordering of $ p_4(8) $ with this property. $ p_5(10) $, $ p_6(12) $, and others also have unique orderings like this, but as $n$ and $k$ increase, $ p_k(n) $ has many more orderings that meet this criterion.

My questions are:

- Is there a procedure to generate one of these orderings for $ p_k(n) $? I can generate all $k$-sized partitions and look for a Hamiltonian path within them, but I'm hoping there's a smarter, faster approach.
- Can any of these orderings be thought of as canonical? [Some thought](https://oeis.org/wiki/Orderings_of_partitions) has been given to orderings of partitions, but I can't find an ordering with this property.

Comment: See the algorithms described here : https://jeromekelleher.net/generating-integer-partitions.html (and eliminate those which haven't the good size $k$).

Comment: This looked promising (iterative, iterates once per output), but the length = $k$ filtered list doesn't seem to have the property. For example, for $p_6(12)$, both versions of the algorithm return $\{1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4\}$ and then $\{1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 5\}$.

Comment: Some potentially helpful key words are the sandpile model (on partitions, not graphs), the ice pile model, and Brylawski's work on the dominance partial order.  (Knuth in *The Art of Computer Programming* 4A gives a nice treatment of Hindenburg's method for listing the $k$-part partitions of $n$ in the colex order, but in general it requires moves that affect more than one dot in the Ferrers diagram.)

Comment: @BrianHopkins The unique Hamiltonian orderings of $p_5(10)$ and $p_6(12)$ feature dots "climbing" the pile as well as falling down, but some of these partial orders could definitely take me somewhere. Thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Carla Savage's 1989 paper "Gray Code Sequences of Partitions" (Journal of Algorithms 10, 577-595) does what you need.  There are two primary algorithms, some trickier work when $n$ is close to double the number of parts (as in the examples you've mentioned), and a few special cases.  Most of the work is done on $P(n,k)$ defined as partitions of $n$ into at most $k$ parts, whereas you want exactly $k$ parts. Towards the end, though, she explains that the algorithm guarantees the exactly $k$ parts result as well.  Whether the order is canonical may be a matter of taste, as the algorithm is a bit complicated.

To see more about related problems, Torsten Mütze recently posted [Combinatorial Gray codes - an updated survey](https://arxiv.org/abs/2202.01280) to the arXiv.

Comment: This turned out to be just what I needed! Thanks, Dr. Hopkins.

Answer (score 1):

Success! I wrote a Python implementation of Dr. Savage's algorithm, which can be found here: https://gist.github.com/thquinn/97f3ed433a6fe5796dbbd054de851b84

Tested up to $1\leq k\leq n\leq50$.

Comment: Very nice.  Have you tried modifying it to address your initial condition of exactly $k$ parts?  For example, $L(7,7)$ includes the sequence 31111, 22111, 2221, 322, 3211, 331, 43, 421, 4111, 511, where neither the 3-part partitions nor their conjugates (first part 3) are adjacent.

Comment: Should work for that: prepending $k$ to each partition in $L(n - k, k)$ gets you every partition with highest value $k$, which are the conjugates of partitions of $n$ into exactly $k$ parts.

Comment: So to get your sequence $p_3(7)$, we start with $L(4,3) = (1111, 211, 22, 31)$ and prepend 3 to get $(31111, 3211, 322, 331)$ which have conjugates $(511, 421, 331, 322)$.  Looks good!